# android:ripple effect problem (background color fixed) on TextView of recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I searched all ripple android effect solutions and tried but I couldn't solve.

This effect (It's ripple ,but not ripple) fixed until click other textview.*/

1)

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" -> LinearLayout
```

and no background in TextView(doesn't work)

2) 
and attached forground like same attr to TextView or LinearLayout or both(fail)
and recyclerView itself

3) custom ripple(drawable -> .xml)(fail)

4) programmatically(fail)

5) api  ? minSdk ? version up (over 23 in android studio)and tried all above (fail)

anyway I tried all stackoverflow solution I could find and other web but i didn't.

--listitme.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/words"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

//recyclerView

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>
others....
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        />
...others
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

//viewHolder

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public JeolWordsAllInOneAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context= parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        JeolWordsAllInOneAdapter.ViewHolder vh= new JeolWordsAllInOneAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JeolWordsAllInOneAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String item = listViewItems.get(position);
        holder.words.setText(item);
        holder.words.setTextSize(Float.valueOf(textsize));

    }
```

Image Samples

[Recyclerview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6tbi.png)

[Recyclerview 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrzR8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something in your question, you don't need to make the text clickable. Try changing your listitem.xml to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/words"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wow! it works! thank you! but Is it imipossible ```android:textIsSelectable="true"``` on textView?